# How can an ROC AUC and its 95%CI be estimated from repeated crossvalidation?

Tags: r, cross-validation, roc, auc

I'm using repeated 100 times 10-fold cross-validation to provide internal validation of a logistic regression model. What is the best way to obtain the ROC AUC and it's 95% CI from this data. If I calculate the ROC AUC of each repetition (100 groups) and then calculate the median, 95% CI from this the variance will be much lower than if I calculate it from each fold (1000 groups).
The histogram of the folds from a sample dataset in R (etitanic) looks much more normally distributed for the folds than the repeats. Thank you for your advice.

[image: Test1 shows the distribution of the AUCs of all folds]

[image: Test2 shows the distribution of the AUCs of all cross-validation repeats]

Comment: That's called regression to the mean. For Confidence Intervals you should use bootstrap instead of CV.

Comment: Hi @Calimo, thanks for the reply and for developing pROC. Is there good evidence to use bootstrapping instead of CV, I saw a previous paper that used CV (1)? Would I use the same approach for estimating its values ie the median and 95% CI of all replicates from the caret package? Ref:1. https://biostats.bepress.com/ucbbiostat/paper304/

Comment: The downside of using caret is that it will output model probabilites so I won't be able to get the biomarker cut-offs/ thresholds. Is there a method of internal validation where I can use the same method for single biomarkers as logistic regression models to ensure consistency? ie  I would like to know the cut-off for a certain specificity but use the same internal validation method ie cross-validation I'm using for the logistic regression models.